# RccpArmadillo and RccpGSL not loading in RStudio in Windows

Tags: c++, r, rstudio, rcpp

I have a C++ function:

```
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
IntegerVector fnGender(int item, bool replace, NumericVector vSegPop, 
  IntegerVector vLevelsGender, NumericMatrix mGender) {    
  RNGScope scope;
  IntegerVector ret = RcppArmadillo::sample(vLevelsGender, vSegPop(item),
    replace, mGender.row(item)) ;
  return ret;
}
```

I am using the RccpArmadillo::sample function instead of base R's sample().

When I load the function using sourceCpp, I get the following error.

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/Users/USER/DOCUME~1/R/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG     -
I"C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/R-3.1.1/library/Rcpp/include"  -
I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include" -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c Code.cpp -o Code.o
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` in your code?

Comment: What @user1 said: you're not actually providing the error message, you're providing the compile messages.

Comment: And the compilation invocation clearly shows the missing `-I...` for RcppArmadillo, so Roland is spot on.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of the season, here is your code with the two changes suggested in the comments -- which builds fine for me on Windows:

```
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector fnGender(int item, bool replace, NumericVector vSegPop, 
  IntegerVector vLevelsGender, NumericMatrix mGender) {    
  IntegerVector ret = 
    RcppArmadillo::sample(vLevelsGender, vSegPop(item),
                          replace, mGender.row(item)) ;
  return ret;
}
```

I removed `RNGScope scope;` as the Rcpp build framework used here automagically adds it anyway.